# Performing a search within my site

Tags: php, search

I have a database of beers. I have pages set up to display them by style and country. But I also want create a search function to find a particular beer (for example I'm at a store and I want to know if I have already drank that beer or not).

Doing a practice search using phpadmin and with their 'create php code' I got this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `beer` WHERE `beer_name` LIKE 'highgate bitter'";
```

Is there and easy way to make a search?

Comment: try, fail, THEN post (with fail code)

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question... a query using like is the way to go. Make a form with a textfield, and use the value of that textfield in your LIKE query. Voila!

Gr.